# SQL matching column with another in same table, IN statement not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make an SQL query. I'm still new to SQL, maybe someone could give me some direction, or let me know if this is even possible.

Please note I have read up on IN, ALL, INNER JOIN etc and I still cannot get the proper query. I have tried to find the solution for hours.

These are my table columns:

```
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| route     | varchar(100)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| stopID    | varchar(5)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| stopName  | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Latitude  | float(10,6)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Longitude | float(10,6)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| timeList  | varchar(1000) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| day       | varchar(5)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I need the stopId's and stopNames where the stopName matches another stopName with a different stopID AND the day='Week' (Otherwise a total of 3 results will come back since there are Week, Sat, Sun days.).

```
| 16    | 1639   | MYUNIQUESTOPNAME  |   43.514000 |  -80.199600 | (a really long list of times) | Week  |
| 5     | 0530   | MYUNIQUESTOPNAME  |   43.514000 |  -80.199600 | (a really long list of times) | Week  |

SELECT stopID,stopName FROM Routes WHERE stopName='MYUNIQUESTOPNAME' AND day='Week';
+--------+---------------------------+
| stopID | stopName                  |
+--------+---------------------------+
| 1612   | MYUNIQUESTOPNAME          |
| 1639   | MYUNIQUESTOPNAME          |
| 0530   | MYUNIQUESTOPNAME          |
+--------+---------------------------+
```

Gives me what I want, but that's only for one stop, and doing it this way, I would have to do it manually. There's a lot of stops. 
Secondly, I would then want all the id's and names that have NO matches (are unique to the bus route).

```
SELECT stopID,stopName FROM Routes WHERE stopName IN (SELECT stopName FROM Routes WHERE day='Week') AND day='Week';
```

The above DOES NOT GIVE ME WHAT I WANT. All my searching implies that it is though... What am I doing incorrectly...?

mysql version is 5.5.41-0+wheezy1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a self join on the table (routes) on the column (stopName) and then get all the results where day=week and stopIds are not same. This would give you the answer to the first query

```
Select unq.stopId, unq.stopName from Routes unq join Routes other on other.stopName=unq.stopName where unq.stopId!= other.stopId and unq.day = 'Week'
```

For the second one where you want only those which are unique, do a group by on stop name and pick the records where grouping results in only one record

```
Select unq.stopId, unq.stopName from Routes unq group by unq.stopName having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, i just had to add  unq.day='Week' at the end  and other.day='Week' inside to remove column 'day' WHERE clause ambiguous error

Answer (score 0):

With the query you are running you will return all stops as the nested query will always contain the stop from the outer query.
Use the following to stop this from happening.

```
SELECT stopID,stopName AS s1
FROM Routes 
WHERE stopName IN (SELECT stopName AS s2
                   FROM Routes 
                   WHERE day='Week'
                   AND s1.stopID <> s2.stopID) 
AND day='Week';
```

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 's1' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of stops where the list is small ad you can use IN:

```
SELECT stopID,stopName 
FROM Routes 
WHERE stopName IN ('MYUNIQUESTOPNAME', 'ANOTHERNAME', 'AThirdNAME') AND day='Week';
```

To get a list of stops where the stopName exists more than once for a week day:

```
SELECT stopID,stopName 
FROM Routes 
WHERE stopName IN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT stopName 
   FROM Routes 
   WHERE day = 'Week' 
   GROUP BY stopName 
   HAVING COUNT(stopName) > 1) 
AND day='Week';
```